# iOS7 status bar issue that I can't figure out

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, ios7, statusbar

I have those 2 issues in iOS7 that I can't figure out.

The first issue is that the TableView rows goes beneath the Status Bar, how can I disable it, or to make the section header of the table view to be under the status bar all the time?

[image: status bar]
[image: status bar]

The second issue that I have is on the navigation controller the status bar seems to be black with black background and I don't know how to fix it, the view controllers background is white, but the status bar reminds black and I don't know why.

[image: black status bar]

UPDATE:

Still no answer.

Comment: Same problem here with your first problem. I solved your second problem with making my navigationbarimage higher. See my code below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the answer in another post, please check it everyone who has problems with iOS6-7 and StatusBar:

[UIStatusBar as in Facebook new iOS7 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19137428/uistatusbar-as-in-facebook-new-ios7-application)

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do following code.

You will have to check condition for ios7.

You will need these two delegate methods for tableview.

Check my code below.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];

    int versionValue=[currSysVer intValue];

    if(versionValue>=7)
    {
        return 60;
    }
    return 0;
}

- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   UIView  *headerView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 60)];

    [headerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    return headerView;
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I'm already using those 2 delegate methods, replaced your methods with mine, still won't work, looks the same and acts the same. I just can figure it out.

Comment: this worked for me in xcode5 and ios7. Check if you have set delegates properly.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer for your second issue!**

Put in your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
   if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {

        [self customizeios7];

    } else {

        [self customizeios6];

    }
```

And make these 2 voids:

```
-(void)customizeios6 {

    UIImage *navBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationbar-ios6"];

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBackgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

}

-(void)customizeios7 {

    // SET STATUSBAR TEXT WHITE

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];

    // SET NAVIGATION IMAGE

    UIImage *navBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationbar-ios7"];

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBackgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

}
```

The image dimensions for your UINavigationBar:

**For iOS 6:**

640px / 88px

**For iOS 7:**

640px / 128px

Answer (score 0):

use these lines of code

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)]) {
    // iOS 7
    [self prefersStatusBarHidden];
    [self performSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)];
} else {
    // iOS 6
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
}
```

and

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
   return YES;
}
```

Comment: add with in viewDidLoad method