# Hide Battry Icon in ios7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, statusbar

[image]

Hi All
 I am making an app which has a side menu as shown in image. In whole app status bar is visible but in the situation when side menu is open then i have to hide battery icon as in image.

Any idea how to do that.
App is for iOS 7 only

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Be careful , some thing like this can be reject by apple.

Comment: You can hide whole status bar.

Comment: oh Apology for this question....My mistake

Answer (score 1):

it is not possible in iOS, you only hide status bar fully in iOS.

Comment: It is possible see this https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/base-crm-and-sales-tracking/id488534576?mt=8

Comment: it will hide only the navigation and status bar colour are same

Comment: set navigation bar tint color as white

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. You can do either hiding the status bar or changing the status bar color as like of in Facebook application.

For status bar color change refer the link [UIStatusBar as in Facebook new iOS7 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19137428/uistatusbar-as-in-facebook-new-ios7-application)